# PyTorch - create padded tensor from sequences of variable length

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking for a good *(efficient and preferably simple)* way to create padded tensor from sequences of variable length / shape. The best way I can imagine so far is a naive approach like this:

```
import torch
seq = [1,2,3]      # seq of variable length
max_len = 5        # maximum length of seq
t = torch.zeros(5) # padding value
for i, e in enumerate(seq):
    t[i] = e
print(t)
```

Output:

```
tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.])
```

**Is there a better way to do so?**

*I haven't found something yet, but I guess there must be something better.*

*I'm thinking of some function to extend the sequence tensor to the desired shape with the desired padding. Or something to create the padded tensor directly from the sequence. But of course other approaches are welcome too.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make your variable length sequence a `torch.Tensor` and use [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.pad)

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

seq = torch.Tensor([1,2,3])      # seq of variable length
print(F.pad(seq, pad=(0, 2), mode='constant', value=0))
 1
 2
 3
 0
 0
[torch.FloatTensor of size 5]
```

Signature of `F.pad` is:

- `input`: input tensor that is your variable length sequence.
- `pad`: m-elem tuple, where (m/2) ≤ input dimensions and m is even. In 1D case first element is how much padding to the left and second element how much padding to the right of your sequence.
- `mode`: fill the padding with a constant or by replicating the border or reflecting the values.
- `value`: the fill value if you choose a constant padding.

Answer (score 17):

*As an add-on to the answer already given by @iacolippo:*

I just stumbled over [`torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html), as this works a bit differently as the solution by @iacolippo I post it here.

It takes a list of tensors of variable length and combines them to a matrix - padding all sequences to the longest given sequence.

**Code example:**

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
b = torch.tensor([1,2])
c = torch.tensor([1])
torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence((a,b,c), batch_first=True)
```

**Output - padded sequences:**

```
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  2,  0],
        [ 1,  0,  0]])
```

---

*Signature of [`torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html):*

> **torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence** *(sequences, batch_first=False, padding_value=0)*
>
> - **sequences** (`list[Tensor]`) – list of variable length sequences.
> - **batch_first** (`bool`, *optional*) – output will be in `B x T x *` if True, or in `T x B x *` otherwise
> - **padding_value** (`float`, *optional*) – value for padded elements. Default: `0`.

Comment: sir i have a question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429393/how-to-convert-pandas-multiple-columns-of-text-into-tensors/68432623?noredirect=1#comment121992042_68432623.         But after converting each column into tensors as the first answer suggested. How to implement lstm or other models. Someone suggested pad_sequence and I am not sure how it would be done. Can you please answer there?

Comment: Would like to suggest updating to the following URL

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html